# Flask - Submit a form (text area, files, ...) with Javascript/JQuery/Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, flask

I would like to use JQuery/Javascript/Ajax to send what's in the form (text area, files, ...)  to one function of my Flask app.

```
<form action='' method="post">
       <label for="label">Example</label><br>
       <textarea name="text_area" id="text_area" rows="10" cols="100">
       </textarea><br>
       <i>Upload a file : <input type='file' id="file_query" name='file_query'></i>
       <br><br>
       <a id="submit_all">Submit</a> 
</form>
```

I would like to be able to access what have been sent in request.form and request.files

How to do it and keep it simple ?

Comment: use `FormData` with ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did follow what @Jai said in his comment : `"use FormData with ajax"`

The [following](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) worked and I was able to get back the data inside my function.

```
$(function() {
    $('#submit_btn').on('click', function(){
       var fd = new FormData(document.querySelector("form"));
       $.ajax({
          url: "/_apply_function",
          type: "POST",
          data: fd,
          processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
          contentType: false   // tell jQuery not to set contentType
        });
      });
 });
```